# Angular JS - UI-router not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angularjs-routing, angular-ui-router

router working within my Angular JS app. My code is:

Script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui-router','mainControl','ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize']);
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/splash');
  //
  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
    .state('splash', {
      url: '/splash',
      templateUrl: 'partials/splash2.html',
      controller: 'MainControl'
    })
    .state('advice', {
      url: '/advice',
      templateUrl: 'partials/advice.html',
      controller: 'MainControl'
    })
    .state('main', {
      url: '/main',
      templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
      controller: 'MainControl'
    })
    });
```

I was has successfully integrated ngRoute into my project, but for some reason the routing was not working in Safari and IE, So this is why I am now trying to integrate the UI-router into my project so that I can successfully get the routing working within my Application.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Both ngRouter and uiRouter work on all browsers. Which error stack are you getting? At first sight your code looks ok. Why do you use the same controller on all your routes?

Comment: ngRouter and uiRouter now work in Chrome and Firefox, but the app just does not work in IE and safari?

Comment: Any error in the console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are having typo, module name should be `ui.router` instead of `ui-router` while creating `myApp` module for your app.

Comment: @Sole Glad to help you THanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Besides `ui.router`, you should add the js file for ngSanitize (`<script src="angular-sanitize.js">`)